# TTS text to speech using google translator

Tags: android, google-chrome, web, text-to-speech, google-translate

I'm using the TTS of google translator in javascript as follows:

```
<script>
  function playGoogle()
  {
    var audio = new Audio();
    audio.src ="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q='hello World'";
    audio.play();
  }
</script>
```

It is working on ios devices (using safari and chrome) but not on Android (using chrome). I used this url in chrome: 
http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=hello World 
On ios devices(chrome and safari) "hello world" is played without clicking on the play button, but on android devices you need to click on the play button in order to hear the 'hello world'.

I think it is the reason why my script doesnt work on Android devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that playGoogle is called via a userGesture such as a click on a button.  Chrome for Android will not play Audio or Video without a gesture first.

Comment: so....what can i do? i want that the TTS will be played without clicking on the "Play" button(like ios devices)...

Comment: Use the TTS library that will land soon in Chrome. (https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html)